# Newtonsoft.Json: Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: ,

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core, json.net

After the project update to .NET 6 from .NET Core 3.1 the Newtonsoft package fails to deserialize object. The error that I'm getting is :

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: ExportOrder. Newtonsoft.Json: Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: ,. Path '', line 1, position 39.

var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderRequest>(myQueueItem);
```

The OrderRequest class:

```
  public class OrderRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public string RunId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

And the myQueueItem that I'm sending is:

```
{
    "input": "{\"06-24T07-05-35Z48\",\"IsSuccess\":true,\"Message\":\"Completed Successfully\"}"
}
```

Is it better idea to migrate to System.Text.JSON ?

Comment: You miss a `"` at the end of the string

Comment: My bad its corrected. it was a typo.

Comment: Try setting this property name `[JsonProperty("input")]` in your  OrderRequest class.

Comment: The value of your `input` is not valid JSON: the date value it starts with has no property name. It also doesn't have a `RunId` property, which your model seems to expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you json is not valid, it should be

```
var json="{\"input\": \"06-24T07-05-35Z48\",\"IsSuccess\":true,\"Message\":\"Completed Successfully\"}";

OrderRequest orderRequest=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderRequest>(json);

string message = orderRequest.Message; //Completed Successfully
```

class

```
public class OrderRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("input")]
    public string Input { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```